# Why does the negative z-index removes the hovering capabilities of non-statically positioned element?

Tags: html, css, hover, position

I just noticed that setting  `z-index:-1` to non-statically positioned elements removes their hovering capabilities. Surprisingly the hovering capabilities of absolutely and fixed positioned elements varie  with conditions,

> - Absolutely/Fixed positioned elements loose the hovering capability partially only if there is some text written after them. Hovering over near the top border doesn't work. If there is nothing after them then hovering works properly.
> - Relatively positioned elements loose the hovering capability completely even if there is no text after them.

**Relatively positioned:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: block; 
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.tooltip:hover {
    color:red; background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">
Hover over me
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**Absolutely positioned with text after it:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: block; 
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.tooltip:hover {
    color:red; background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">
Hover over me
</div>

RAndom text

</body>
</html>
```

**Fixed positioned with text after it:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    display: block; 
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.tooltip:hover {
    color:red; background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">
Hover over me
</div>

RAndom text

</body>
</html>
```

**Question:** Why does setting z-index:-1 remove the hovering capabilities of absolutely/fixed positioned elements, partially if there is text after them, and relative positioned elements completely?

---

**Addendum:** From the help of other users I've understood the concept. But there all still some doubts left:

> - Why does the whole viewport get the color of the body? The border shows that body is not all over the view port but if we give the body some color then the whole view port gets that color.
> - If we hover over the inner child box, having `z-index:-1`, then the parent container(i.e. body) is automatically hovered. Why?

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal, hovering capability of relatively positioned element is also removed; that's why I wrote the term _non-static_. Now I understand that z-index:-1 puts the relatively positioned element behind one layer.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Run my first code, under the section **Relatively positioned**. The relatively positioned _Hover over me_ block isn't hoverable.

Answer (score 5):

**You may know how z-index works?**

[image]

1. When you use positive z-index, the element is moved to the up layer.
2. When you use negative z-index, the element is moved to the down layer.

**Now, lets look at the following pictures:**

[image]

In the preceding picture, the flow of the document is normal. As the element div is positioned relatively the height of the wrapper element is increased automatically. And the z-index is set to 1 layer up to the wrapper element. We can hover over the element as it is above the wrapper.

[image]

In the preceding picture, the z-index of the element is set to -1 which means the element layer is 1 layer down to the wrapper element. And the covering wrapper element is above the element by which we cannot hover over that element.

[image]

In the preceding picture, the flow of the document is not normal, so called `out of flow`. As the div element is positioned fixed or absolutely the height of the wrapper element is not increased. And the z-index is set to 1 layer up to the wrapper element and we can hover over the element.

[image]

In the preceding picture, the z-index of the element is set to -1 which means the element layer is 1 layer down to the wrapper element. And the covering wrapper element is above the element but still the element is not covered by the wrapper as its height is not increased up to the layer that's why we can still hover over the element that is positioned fixed or absolutely.

Hope! This makes clear up things to you about z-index.

Comment: Hello Bhojendra, I've got something to show you. I've almost remake the weird behavior when partial hovering is possible.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103163/z-index

Comment: I found the answer. Just give `body` some background color. The body is acting as the container.

Answer (score 2):

If an element is transparent and the element with `z-index:-1;` is 'under' it. This stops the hover effects.

Z-index can you see as elevations in a building, and you watching it from birdseye. You can't reach the basement if there is a floor above it, even if its build from glass.

If no elements are above it, it can be hovered and you can 'reach te basement'.

Comment: Why can it be hovered completely when is no text after the box. The parent vieport is still there and should act as second building above the z-indexed:-1 building.

Comment: Your element is in your case behind the transparent body because the body is default z-index 0.

Comment: What happens with relatively positioned element? Isn't it too behind the transparent parent container? And why are absolute/fixed positioned elements partially hoverable when there is a text after them?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer myself. Thanks to user BoltClock and Bhojendra. I don't know why BoltClock deleted their answer. They were right in that the parent container obscures the child box depending upon the amount of text in the parent container. To visualize it all I had to do was add a border to `body`. I've given red dotted border to body in the following codes:

**Relatively positioned:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: block; 
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.tooltip:hover {
    color:red; background-color: yellow;
}

body {
        border: 2px dotted red; 
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">
Hover over me; I'm underneath the body.
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**Absolutely positioned with text after it:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: block; 
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.tooltip:hover {
    color:red; background-color: yellow;
}

body { 
       border: 2px dotted red;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">
Hover over me
</div>

RAndom text

</body>
</html>
```

**Fixed positioned with text after it:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    display: block; 
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.tooltip:hover {
    color:red; background-color: yellow;
}

body { 
       border: 2px dotted red;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">
Hover over me
</div>

RAndom text

</body>
</html>
```

As can be seen, the body is covering the *Hover over me* box.

---

Although I got what was going wrong with hovering. There are still some doubts which have been added to the original question.

Comment: I have provided you the well answer. I don't think this is an answer to you. Seems like a question, not?

Comment: All of your snippets here going well as my answer explains this.

Comment: You should delete your answer. As this is not really an answer.

Comment: Please carefully see all of my pictures to get idea what I am trying to say. You'll get all answer from that.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I was busy so couldn't reply earlier. My main question was actually about partial hovering on the box. I am removing the question part from my answer and adding to the original question.

Comment: Just see the picture in my answer, you will get understand.

Comment: Partial hover is possible because the element is outside of the wrapper. Check my picture 2 and 3.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I've understood it. Your answer and boltclock's answer cleared my concepts. But I've some minute doubts remaining. The thing was that `body` is the wrapper and when we add some text into the body the body extends itself horizontally covering the absolutely positioned element partially.

Comment: As to why I am not accepting your answer yet is because from your pictures partial hovering isn't obvious. And I've not yet understood the  addendum portion of my question.

Comment: Okay, I will show you partial hovering picture. Hope you'll understand then.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal You don't need to do that. I've already understood it. Don't waste your time. If you want to help then please explain about my **addendum portion**. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: What if you have mask in your mouth can you touch? No. Okay, now if there is a whole in the  mask then that part can be touched. Like that partial hover is possible as you are positioning the div half inside and half outside of the wrapper. That's it. Hope you'll understand.