# bootstrap btn hover not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pulling my hair out to try and find out why my hover background-color isn't working for my custom buttons. I'm using twitter Bootstrap v3.

Here is the css code:

```
.btn-slide1 {
padding: 20px 40px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 700;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
color:#fff;
background-color:#5cb85c;
border-color:#4cae4c;
}

 .btn-slide1:hover,.btn-slide1:focus,.btn-slide1:active {background-color: #9966cc !important;}
```

Here is the html:

```
  <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/slide1.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Turn your art into a masterpiece</h2><br>
                <a class="btn btn-slide1" href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've tried adding '.btn' to the css code, and that hasn't worked.

It's part of a carousel slider. Could this be the reason?

This is the page in question: [index_test.html](http://www.customkidart.com/index_test.html)

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the page through Chrome's inspect element, it seems that the problem does lie in the carousel – the mouse is not registering as hovering over the element

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here. There is a negative z-index property on the carousel items. In full-slider.css line 124.

```
.carousel, .item, .active {
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -10 !important;
}
```

Changing it to 0 or more will fix. What's happening is it's behind the element that you're actually hovering.. You can check out this link for more on z-index and different behaviours. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35330122/2971290

Answer (score 0):

Remove the z-index in /css/full-slider.css line 124.
It will be fine then.

Comment: Oh, thank goodness! It worked! Thanks everyone. I'm sure I wouldn't have figured that out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that my btn:hover didn't work.
I changed Bootstrap link (after that worked)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).